# Finding smallest number greater than a given number (Interview)

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, complexity-theory

I was given an interview question recently, say u have an ordered list of numbers(the number of elements can be quite big in the order of 100000) and u are to find the smallest number greater than a given number suggest ways to do this in O(log n) time... my first guess was using a tree like data structure to which the interviewer said yes but they have an overhead of building these trees and wether i could suggest another method ? My obvious answer was binary search using arrays though was wondering if that would work or if there are any other?

Comment: [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: Yes, they asked if you know binary search.

Comment: I think binary search is what they wanted to hear. On the other hand without knowing how this list is organized it's really impossible to give the right advice. It might be given as a linked list. Pretty much ordered, but obviously without random access to the members. In this case there would be not way to do in any faster than O(n).

Comment: Yes binary search is what i had suggested but wondering if there are any other than binary search?

Comment: Depending on the data structure that holds the numbers, there may be; an sorted AVL tree for example will also do it in O(log n), but in effect it's no different than a binary search. Another data structure that would achieve it are skip lists.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the type of the List You are using .

If it was not indexed list then O(logN) wont be possible without Any restructuring .

So if it was an indexed list .

You can search by divide .

Compare the target with a[n/2]

If the a[n/2] less then target .. your search space is reduced . start from a[n/2+1]..a[n-1]

with same approach a recursive algo until you find a pair such that a[i] < target < a[i+1]

that will be end and a[i+1] is your answer..!!

Comment: What is the difference between your approach and sort + the binary search that OP proposed?

Comment: Yes binary search is what i had suggested but wondering if there are any other than binary search?

Comment: Binary Search finds for any exact number. This is same approach of Binary search but not only to find exact number .